# Vim: Use + as default register only for yank command

Tags: vim, clipboard

I'd like to use + register (system clipboard) **only** for yank command (that is, don't overwrite this register on `dd` or other commands).

```
:set clipboard+=unnamed
```

won't work, because it introduces `dd` overwriting described above.

Comment: `set clipboard=unnamedplus` uses + for all clipboard operations. [:help clipboard-unnamedplus](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#clipboard-unnamedplus). Just leaving it here in case anyone needs that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can overwrite the default yank commands so that they default to the system clipboard, unless another register is explicitly given:

```
:nnoremap <expr> y (v:register ==# '"' ? '"+' : '') . 'y'
:nnoremap <expr> yy (v:register ==# '"' ? '"+' : '') . 'yy'
:nnoremap <expr> Y (v:register ==# '"' ? '"+' : '') . 'Y'
:xnoremap <expr> y (v:register ==# '"' ? '"+' : '') . 'y'
:xnoremap <expr> Y (v:register ==# '"' ? '"+' : '') . 'Y'
```

Comment: Thank you. Now I also use the same but for `p` and `d`

Answer (score 6):

`d` is more like "cut" than "delete". What you get is normal behavior.

You can use the "black hole register", though: `"_d`. I have mapped it to `<leader>d`.

Comment: +1 I almost never use the black hole register because it never occurred to me to map it to something easy like `<leader>d`

Comment: And it works just like `d`. With `let mapleader=","`: `,dd`, `,di(`, `,dtx`, `,d/foo`.