# How make Vim paste to always paste from register 0 unless it's specified

Tags: vim

Register `0` in Vim should contain the result of the last yank command (<kbd>y</kbd>).

Now, instead of <kbd>p</kbd> pasting from the default register (`""`), I want <kbd>p</kbd> to paste from register `0`, *unless* a register is specified (through <kbd>"+p</kbd>, for example).

How can I do this in my .vimrc?

I tried this:

```
xnoremap p "'v:register'p
```

But I don't know how to do the “use-the-specified-register-otherwise-0” part.

Comment: how about E.g. `nnoremap <leader>p "0p` in this way, you could press `p, "+p...` to paste in vim default way. and press `<leader>p` to paste your `0` register. is it ok for you?

Comment: You could do that, but having p to paste from register 0 by default is preferable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13380643/vim-use-as-default-register-only-for-yank-command)

```
:nnoremap <expr> p (v:register ==# '"' ? '"0' : '') . 'p'
:nnoremap <expr> P (v:register ==# '"' ? '"0' : '') . 'P'
:xnoremap <expr> p (v:register ==# '"' ? '"0' : '') . 'p'
:xnoremap <expr> P (v:register ==# '"' ? '"0' : '') . 'P'
```

Answer (score 0):

For Neovim I just

```lua
map({ "n", "v" }, "p", [["0p]], { desc = "Paste yank" })
map({ "n", "v" }, "P", [["0P]], { desc = "Paste yank" })
```

where

```lua
local function map(mode, lhs, rhs, opts)
  vim.keymap.set(mode, lhs, rhs, opts)
end
```